# No display after changing resolution with xrandr

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm new on Linux and I'm having some problems with my monitor. My monitor isn't recognized by Ubuntu, therefore I can't use the resolution I want. To fix this I did the following commands on the terminal with xrandr:

```
cvt 1920 1080
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP2 1920x1080_60.00
```

It works just fine, but after I reboot the system I get no display, although I can listen to the sound of the boot. I've already reinstalled Ubuntu many times and still get this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the make and model of your monitor?  What are you using for graphics hardware?

Comment: Sorry English is my second language I don't what you mean by "make of your monitor". The model is a Philips 221EL2 and the graphic card is Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphic

Comment: Make is Philips, model is 221EL2.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I was hoping that someone with more experience would take a look at your question.  There should be no problem with 1920x1080 on your monitor.  Did you install Ubuntu "from scratch", or did you upgrade from another version of Ubuntu?  If you boot to the install DVD or USB stick and choose "Try Ubuntu", does the monitor work then?

Comment: Hey man thanks for your help but I think the problem was solved. I've download the distro one more time and everything seems to being working good so far.

Comment: Good deal, I'm glad it's working for you!